# objective c and cocoa convert decimal feet to feet and inches?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, decimal

How would I convert something like 5.5 into 5 foot 6 inches.  I am doing this in xcode using objective c and xcode.

Any help appreciated

Comment: To help you improve your Google-fu, I submit that Krishnabhada's answer is correct because Objective-C is "C with benefits". This means your scope can be much wider than just Objective-C when looking for solutions to your problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there are any native function to do that. Anyhow this will work

```
CGFloat decimal = 12.5;
NSInteger feet = (NSInteger)decimal;
CGFloat fraction = decimal - feet;
NSInteger inches = (NSInteger)(12.0 * fraction);
NSLog(@"%f feet %f inches", feet,inches);
```

Comment: Thanks that works, couuld you also tell how to allow the entering of this into a nstextfield. e.g. if i put 5.11 it would read it as 5 foot 11 inches and not 5.1.  your previous code works for the calculations perfectly

Comment: I am not familiar with mac development, But I feel you should implement any NSTextFieldDelegate methods, and replace the textfield content with correct (calculate using above code)value after user finish with entering the value.

Comment: Krishnabhada: The delegate methods are actually not the way to do it. See NSFormatter.

Comment: Also, I converted int/float and formatting to use NSInteger/CGFloat (32/64 happiness).